# How to get the Jenkins user who installed specific plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins and need support to get list of installed plugins and corresponding users whom installed it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a list of Plugins I don't see any problem. Just go to `Jenkins --> Manage Jenkins --> Manage Plugins` on tab `installed` you get a full List of installed Plugins.
If you also want to see what job is using which plugin, I can recomend you the `Plugin Usage Plugin`. You will get a new configuration option called `Plugin Usage`. There you can see also all your plugins and where they are used.

---

Now to your real question: You can find that information in the `jenkins.log` file.

```
Sep 30, 2019 4:04:46 PM hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob run
INFO: Starting the installation of <Plugin> on behalf of <Username>
```

So if you do something like `grep "INFO: Starting the" jenkins.log` you will get the full list of "plugin action":

```
INFO: Starting the downgrade of AnsiColor on behalf of <Username>
INFO: Starting the installation of AnsiColor on behalf of <Username>
INFO: Starting the installation of NAnt on behalf of <Username>
```